# PHP: print a variable contained in a method

Tags: php, function, class, paypal, try-catch

I hope someone can help me with this:
I have 2 php file to elaborate paypal IPN, paypalIPN.php and ipnlistener.php.
ipnlistener.php contains IpnListener class with many functions inside as follow:

```
class IpnListener
{       

    /**
     *  If true, the recommended cURL PHP library is used to send the post back
     *  to PayPal. If flase then fsockopen() is used. Default true.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_curl = true;
    /**
     *  If true, cURL will use the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to follow any
     *  "Location: ..." headers in the response.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $follow_location = false;
    /**
     *  If true, the paypal sandbox URI www.sandbox.paypal.com is used for the
     *  post back. If false, the live URI www.paypal.com is used. Default false.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_sandbox = true;
    /**
     *  The amount of time, in seconds, to wait for the PayPal server to respond
     *  before timing out. Default 30 seconds.
     *
     *  @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 30;
    /**
     * If true, enable SSL certification validation when using cURL
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    public $verify_ssl = true;
    private $_errors = array();
    private $post_data;
    private $rawPostData;               // raw data from php://input
    private $post_uri = '';
    private $response_status = '';
    private $response = '';
    const PAYPAL_HOST = 'www.paypal.com';
    const SANDBOX_HOST = 'www.sandbox.paypal.com';
    /**
     *  Post Back Using cURL
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the cURL library. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is true. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @todo add URL param so function is more dynamic
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    
    protected function curlPost($encoded_data)
    {
        $uri = 'https://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        $this->post_uri = $uri;
        $ch = curl_init();
        if ($this->verify_ssl) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/pp/cert/api_cert_chain.crt');
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $this->follow_location);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->response_status = strval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
        if ($this->response === false || $this->response_status == '0') {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
        return $this->response;
    }
    /**
     *  Post Back Using fsockopen()
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the fsockopen() function. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is false. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @todo add URL param so function is more dynamic
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    protected function fsockPost($encoded_data)
    {
        $uri = 'ssl://'.$this->getPaypalHost();
        $port = '443';
        $this->post_uri = $uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        $fp = fsockopen($uri, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);
        if (!$fp) {
            // fsockopen error
            throw new Exception("fsockopen error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: ".$this->getPaypalHost()."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($encoded_data)."\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        fputs($fp, $header.$encoded_data."\r\n\r\n");
        while(!feof($fp)) {
            if (empty($this->response)) {
                // extract HTTP status from first line
                $this->response .= $status = fgets($fp, 1024);
                $this->response_status = trim(substr($status, 9, 4));
            } else {
                $this->response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
            }
        }
        fclose($fp);
        return $this->response;
    }
    private function getPaypalHost()
    {
        return ($this->use_sandbox) ? self::SANDBOX_HOST : self::PAYPAL_HOST;
    }
    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->_errors;
    }
    private function addError($error)
    {
        $this->_errors[] .= $error;
    }
    public function getPostData()
    {
        return $this->post_data;
    }
    public function getRawPostData()
    {
        return $this->rawPostData;
    }
    /**
     *  Get POST URI
     *
     *  Returns the URI that was used to send the post back to PayPal. This can
     *  be useful for troubleshooting connection problems. The default URI
     *  would be "ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443/cgi-bin/webscr"
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getPostUri()
    {
        return $this->post_uri;
    }
    /**
     *  Get Response
     *
     *  Returns the entire response from PayPal as a string including all the
     *  HTTP headers.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponse()
    {
        return $this->response;
    }
    /**
     *  Get Response Status
     *
     *  Returns the HTTP response status code from PayPal. This should be "200"
     *  if the post back was successful.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponseStatus()
    {
        return $this->response_status;
    }
    /**
     *  Get Text Report
     *
     *  Returns a report of the IPN transaction in plain text format. This is
     *  useful in emails to order processors and system administrators. Override
     *  this method in your own class to customize the report.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getTextReport()
    {
        $r = '';
        // date and POST url
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n[".date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '.$this->getPostUri();
        if ($this->use_curl) {
            $r .= " (curl)\n";
        } else {
            $r .= " (fsockopen)\n";
        }
        // HTTP Response
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n{$this->getResponse()}\n";
        // POST vars
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n";
        foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
            $r .= str_pad($key, 25)."$value\n";
        }
        $r .= "\n\n";
        return $r;
    }
    /**
     *  Process IPN
     *
     *  Handles the IPN post back to PayPal and parsing the response. Call this
     *  method from your IPN listener script. Returns true if the response came
     *  back as "VERIFIED", false if the response came back "INVALID", and
     *  throws an exception if there is an error.
     *
     *  @param array
     *
     *  @return boolean
     */
    public function processIpn($post_data=null)
    {   
                
      
        try
        
        {
            $this->requirePostMethod();     // processIpn() should check itself if data is POST
            // Read POST data
            // reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
            // issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
            if ($post_data === null) {
                $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
            } else {
                $raw_post_data = $post_data;
            }
            $this->rawPostData = $raw_post_data;                            // set raw post data for Class use
            // if post_data is php input stream, make it an array.
            if ( ! is_array($raw_post_data) ) {
                $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
                $this->post_data = $raw_post_array;                             // use post array because it's same as $_POST
                
            } else {
                $this->post_data = $raw_post_data;                              // use post array because it's same as $_POST
            }
            
            
            $myPost = array();
            
            if (isset($raw_post_array)) {
                foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
                    $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
                    if (count($keyval) == 2) {
                        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
            $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
            foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
                if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
                } else {
                    $value = urlencode($value);
                }
                $req .= "&$key=$value";
            }

            //XXX Debug log
            $file = fopen('lastresponse.log', 'w');
            fwrite($file, $req);
            fclose($file);     

            file_put_contents('dati.log', print_r($myPost, true));
            file_put_contents('dato.log', print_r("numero transazione: ".$myPost['txn_id'], true));
         
            //mail("mail@gmail.com","test",print_r($myPost,true));    
            
         


            if ($this->use_curl) {
                $res = $this->curlPost($req);
            } else {
                $res = $this->fsockPost($req);
            }
            if (strpos($res, '200') === false) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid response status: " . $res);
            }
            // Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
            $tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
            $res = trim(end($tokens));
            if (strpos ($res, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
                return true;
            } else if (strpos ($res, "INVALID") !== false) {
                return false;
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Unexpected response from PayPal: " . $res);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->addError($e->getMessage());
            return false;
            
        }
        
        
        return false;
          
    }
    /**
     *  Require Post Method
     *
     *  Throws an exception and sets a HTTP 405 response header if the request
     *  method was not POST.
     */
    public function requirePostMethod()
    {
        // require POST requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
            header('Allow: POST', true, 405);
            throw new Exception("Invalid HTTP request method.");
        }
    }
    
}
```

thanks to this part:

```
file_put_contents('dati.log', print_r($myPost, true));
file_put_contents('dato.log', print_r("numero transazione: ".$myPost['txn_id'], true));
```

I'm able to save a log file with an array of all elements or just only one element of a PayPal transaction.
what I need to do is to print $myPost outside the IpnListener class.
How can I do it?

Comment: _Small Note_ A function in a class is called a **Method**

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly please forgive my ignorance

Answer (score 1):

You could either return value from a method using

```
return $myPost;
```

or (better way) pass a buffering logger object as method parameter and then after method is finished, fetch and print all logger content. See example here:
https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/5.3/Output/BufferedOutput.php

Comment: thank you for your reply, I tried with 'return $myPost'  but I have this error now "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function processIpn() on null in /htdocs/pp/ipnlistener.php:373 Stack trace: #0 /htdocs/pp/PaypalIPN.php(15): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /htdocs/pp/ipnlistener.php on line 373"

Comment: it could be because $myPost is in a try block?

Comment: this error says that method is called not from object, it is nothing to do with the value returned from method. Could you please show updated method and the place it is called?

Comment: and could you explain why actually do you need accees the internal variable of the method outside this method?

Comment: if this var is a result of method, just return it in the end of method body. Else do all needed operations with it inside.

Answer (score 0):

You could go in the class, declare a $tempMyPost as public.

each time you iterate and add something to $myPost, also do $this->tempMyPost

for example if you have

```
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
```

also do

```
            $this->tempMyPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
```

then, go outside the object, below the place you instantiate it and do

print_r($object->tempMyPost);

where $object is the name of the variable that holds your object.